# Bus path in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I want to make the roads of my city bus but the information I've found is
Polygons that mark only two points and follow the streets
Paths between two points using the algritmo of google
but no example of what I'm looking for

Thank you very much for your time

link [to see what i want](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

***the solution***

i find the solution the everything that i need in [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

You will need to make a JSON request URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin= &destination= &transit_mode=bus&key=API_KEY
```

To [request a JSON](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) in your android app, you can see the documentation.